# Compare list using a different variable if list items have the same value in one variable

Tags: java, android

I have a class Person with the attributes of name (string) and age (int):

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Hero(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

I created a list of Person, and compared them using age.

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
persons.add("Andrew", 18);
persons.add("Barry", 25);
persons.add("Cynthia", 33);
persons.add("Darwin", 33);

Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person lhs, Person rhs) {
        return lhs.getAge() < rhs.getAge() ? -1 : lhs.getAge() == lhs.getAge() ? 0 : 1;
    }
});
```

If the ages of two items are equal, how do I compare them using the name instead?

Comment: Show us your current code and we can tell you how to expand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Java 8, creating a custom `Comparator` is much easier, and you can compare multiple fields.

You can use the following code:

```
Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).thenComparing(Person::getName)
```

And that's it.

You can use it to sort your collection like this:

```
Collections.sort(filteredList, Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).thenComparing(Person::getName))
```